# PowerAutomate SAP TH_SERVER_LIST

Tags: power-automate, sap-basis

I'm doing an automation for the `SM51` transaction in SAP on PowerAutomate.
When I run the flow the output that I need, the State is like this:

[image]

I need the value of the state and it's just showing

> "STATE": "System.Byte[]"

How can I fix this ?

I tried using a converter to string but it's not working.